# Parsing <ul> tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

Consider this code:

```
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
print divTag
for tag in divTag:
    ulTag = soup.find_all("ul", {"class":"classname"})
    print ulTag
    for tag in ulTag:
        liTag = soup.find_all("li", {"class":"classname"})
        print liTag
        for tag in liTag:
            diTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
            print diTag
            for tag in diTag:
                aTags = tag.find_next("a")
                value = aTags.string
                print value
```

It prints only "divTag" & "ulTag". I'm sure all the class names are right. There are about 7 'li' tags within the 'ul' tag but it does not print any of the 'li' tags. Please help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="classname">
<ul auto-load="true" class="classname" data-href="">
<li class="classname">
<div class="classname"><a href="">"value"</a>  string <a href="">string1</a> <a class="muted"><abbr class="timeago" title=" 1 Jun, 2015, 10:23 am">7 hours ago</abbr></a>
</div>
</li>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I basically want to extract the "string" value within the 'a' tag.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample of the HTML you want to parse. And please also follow common Python conventions and use four spaces for each level of indention.

Comment: I've added the HTML code, please do look into it.

Comment: do you want the value for each `a` tag or the value `string` between first two `a`?

Comment: The value of string between the first two 'a'. @Michael

Answer (score 0):

Here every time you are searching in soup. So you are failing. You should search for a tag in it's parent tag.
Try something like this:

```
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
for ulTag in divTag:
    for liTag in ulTag.find_all("li", {"class":"classname"}):
        for tag in liTag.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"}):
            for aTag in tag.find_all('a'):
                print aTag.string
```

For the html you provided, The output is:

```
"value"
string1
7 hours ago
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: The error is gone but it doesn't print anything.. :(

Answer (score 0):

The full solution with a next_sibling

```
ulTag = soup.find("ul", {"class": "classname"})
aTags = ulTag.find_all("a")
for aTag in aTags:
    sibling = aTag.next_sibling
    siblingString = str(sibling).strip()
    if len(siblingString) > 0:
        print siblingString
```